# How to add programmatically product to wishlist in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, product, customer, wishlist, programmatically

I want to add the product to the wishlist in magento2.

What is the way to **programmatically add the product into wishlist in Magento2**?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To do so, you will first have to inject the following in your constructor:

- `Magento\Wishlist\Model\WishlistFactory`
- `Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface`

So update your class constructor like this:

```
protected $_wishlistRepository;

protected $_productRepository;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Wishlist\Model\WishlistFactory $wishlistRepository,
    \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
) {
    $this->_wishlistRepository= $wishlistRepository;
    $this->_productRepository = $productRepository;
    ...
}
```

Then in you can do the following, please note your need both the customer id and the product id to add a product to the wishlist:

```
try {
    $product = $this->_productRepository->getById($productId);
} catch (NoSuchEntityException $e) {
    $product = null;
}

$wishlist = $this->_wishlistRepository->create()->loadByCustomerId($customerId, true);

$wishlist->addNewItem($product);
$wishlist->save();
```

Comment: Hello @Raphael thanks for your valuable reply. I am getting following  error during compilation.

 Class Magento\Wishlist\Model\WishlistRepository does not exist

Comment: @Manish oops I reckon it should be `WishlistFactory` see my update

Comment: Hello  @Raphael, by using above code I am able to add wishlist item successfully, but there is a problem in table 'wishlist_item_option' value column is null. There is no any entry for that.

Comment: @Manish I forgot the `save` method, see the updated code

Comment: Same problem does not save anything on value column of  wishlist_item_option.

Comment: when adding same product to wishlist 2nd time it's deleting from wishlist

Comment: how to do the same ...for multiple wishlists programatically in magento2

Comment: Perfect solution. +1 :)

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism could you please help me on this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/311165/m1-how-to-fetch-wishlist-data-in-csv-format

Comment: not working here - error appears ->  INNER JOIN `catalog_category_product_index_store0` AS `cat_index` ON cat_index.product_id = main_table.product_id AND cat_index.category_id = '0' AND cat_index.visibility IN (3, 2, 4) WHERE (`wishlist_id` = '1') AND (`main_table`.`store_id` IN('0')) at /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/DB/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php:91)"} []